# difficult thing in java Generics

Tags: java, generics

can you help me with Generics?

now I have

```
public abstract class TestWsClient extends WsRpcClient {
    public abstract void clientMethod(TestObject testObject);
}
public interface TestWsServer extends WsRpcServer<TestWsClient> {
    public abstract void serverMethod(String message, TestWsClient client, String arg1, int arg2, TestObject objTest);
}
public interface TestWsServerAsync{
  public abstract void serverMethod(String arg1, int arg2, TestObject objTest);
}
class SomeClass{
   public <T extends WsRpcClient> void join(Object server, T client, WsRpcOnStateHandler stateHandler){
   }
}
SomeClass.join(new TestWsServerAsync(){...}, [instaneof TestWsClient])
```

I need check in method `SomeClass.join`. if `TestWsServer` is extended by `WsRpcServer<T>`.

Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. TestWsServer *extends* WsRpcServer, statically. Nothing could possibly pass your check as stated, but when reversed to be correct, nothing could fail it. Probably what you should really do is change the 'Object server' parameter to *specify* the type you require, rather than relying on ill-formulated runtime checks. Not much Generics content here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need check in method SomeClass.join. if TestWsServer is extended by WsRpcServer.

Because you need to check for inheritance against a parameterized type (`WsRpcServer<T>`), you'll need the runtime [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object for `T` to make that check due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).